# Exactly which .NET version does Windows Server 2008 R2 Core support?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, .net, windows-server-core

So, Microsoft added .NET support to Windows Server 2008 R2 Core, but which is the latest version that is supported? I know it has to be either .NET 3.5 or .NET 3.5 SP1, but which is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows Server 2008 R2, as well as Windows 7, comes with built-in **.NET Framework 3.5 SP1**.

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/windowsserver2008r2webtechnologies/thread/ac1bf719-0a88-4b5d-be98-395f2623e805

Answer (score 2):

Vs. 2 and Vs. 3.5 (SP1) are in the box, but Vs. 4 is also supported on Windows Server 2008 R2 Core, but you have to [download a special version](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=22833).